# Comparing two unknown strings and finding match

Tags: java, regex

If I have

```
String x = "test";
String s = "tastaegasghet;
```

you can find t e s t inside the string s. The naive way of doing this with a known string would be something like this:

```
.*t+.*e+.*s+.*t+.*
```

This will return true if we can find the letters *t e s t* in order and any characters inbetween. I want to do the same thing but with two unknown Strings x and s or in otherwords, String s and x can be anything. I don't want something hard coded but something for general use instead.

Comment: You can do this with a single loop, or do you want to use regex to do this?

Comment: You will have an almost *catastrophic backtracking* with your approach for some inputs..

Comment: I'd prefer regex but loop is okay too!

Comment: Then use the advice given by @nhahtdh. Use a loop. It will be faster and less complicated. `O(n)` will be the time -complexity.

Comment: @TreEnt Can you explainn why you have `+` after each letter in your regex (`.*t+.*e+.*s+.*t+.*`)? I don't understand why they're there.

Comment: @Nateowami: It is not necessary, but it does not make the regex wrong.

Comment: I believe + in regex means any number of times, but at least once. I'm new to regex though, so I could be wrong

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but it could also be matched just as easily by the `.*` +1 to question.

Comment: @Nateowami: I see now that they are unnecessary! Thanks for pointing it out. :) 
I understand that doing the thing I want with regex is tedious, but how would I do it without using the loops. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @TreEnt I don't think this could be done without a loop. You can build a regex, but that will take a loop too (and could have issues with special characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pseudocode for looping solution:

```
function (
    needle, // x
    haystack // s
) {
    j = 0
    for (i = 0; i < haystack.length && j < needle.length; i++) {
         if (haystack[i] == needle[j]) {
             j++
         }
    }

    return j == needle.length
}
```

You only need to loop through each character in haystack string and advance the pointer in needle string when you find a matching character. If the pointer reaches the end of the needle string, it means the needle string can be found as a subsequence of the haystack string.

A small optimization you can do is checking `needle.length <= haystack.length` before starting the loop.

#### Just for fun

If you want to go the Cthulhu's way, you can use this construction:

```
(?>.*?t)(?>.*?e)(?>.*?s)(?>.*?t).*+
```

This doesn't have the risk of catastrophic backtracking, and should work similar to the loop above (linear complexity), except that it has a lot of overhead compiling and matching the regex.

Comment: Is there any issue here? Or are you picking problem with my pseudo code?

Comment: @Nateowami: I did mention it is **pseudocode** - you can find the equivalent concept in Java. (It seems that people around here don't appreciate pseudocode).

Comment: Nice thought with `needle.length <= haystack.length`, and +1.

Comment: @nhahtdh how you write two string in java like this haystack[i] == needle[j] without using char array.

Comment: See Nateowami's answer. It is simply `haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(j)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard to just use a loop.

```
String x = "test";
String s = "tastaegasghet";
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length() && index < x.length(); i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == x.charAt(index)) index++;
}
boolean exists = index == x.length();
System.out.println(exists);
```

This should be significantly faster than a regex, at least for longer input.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a simple function, with a loop, instead of a regex. Something like the following:

```
public boolean containsLetters(string a, string b)
{
    char[] aArray = a.toCharArray();
    char[] bArray = b.toCharArray();
    int lettersFound = 0, lastLocation = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++)
    {
        for (lastLocation=lastLocation; lastLocation < bArray.length; lastLocation++)
        {
            if (aArray[i] == bArray[lastLocation])
            {
                lettersFound++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return lettersFound == aArray.length;
}
```

The inner for loop stops the first time it finds the letter. It doens't need to determine if it appears more than once since the function returns a boolean, so this saves some time for large strings. It will only return true if it finds them in order. It remembers the index of the last letter it found, and searches through for the next letter from that location.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Pattern class for this.

```
String x= "yourValue";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Mention your pattern here);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //prints /{item}/
} else {
    System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Java code without using any built-in function

```
    String s1 = "test";
    String s2 = "tastaegasghets";
    char ch[] = new char[s1.length()];
    char ch1[] = new char[s2.length()];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        ch[i] = s1.charAt(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
            ch1[j] = s2.charAt(j);
            if (ch[i] == ch1[j]) {
                k++;
                break;

            }
        }

    }
    if (k == s1.length()) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is O(n*m) where n is the length of the haystack string and m is the length of the needle. The better solution O(n) is already done in at least 2 of the answers before yours. There is also no need for the extra arrays.

Comment: @nhahtdh i see your pseudocode. Have you compare two string haystack[i] == needle[j] in java. one more answer also use two loop & two array. I am not getting you, why are you pointed on my answer.

Comment: The other answer uses 2 loops, but it does not go into the quadratic in worst case. Your code in worst case (no match) will go to quadratic complexity. I think it also doesn't fit the requirement, since the order of the needle string must be retained in the haystack string.